# How to remove borders in rows in the output document (MS Word)?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want exprot document using *JasperReports*. I have exproted the document. How to remove grid lines that are shown in the document? I want to edit the document like a form. How to do that?

Document format: document (winword 2007)

Comment: You need to include more details.  What format did you export in? Do you specify gridlines in the report.  Does it have gridlines in the preview? What relevant code do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set line width for grid in template (using `iReport`, for example). The Border dialog allow you to set border width.